# Starting Keycloak using kc.bat from a folder with space returns "c:\... was unexpected at this time"

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I am using Keycloak version 20.0.3 Quarkus distribution on the windows 10 Operating system. When trying to start using the command from the "c:\program files(x86)\keycloak" folder

> kc.bat start-dev

it returns the following error

**-Djboss.server.config.dir="C:\Program was unexpected at this time.**

Somebody some experience with this?

Comment: Hello, could you give us more insight on your config please ? also, are you following a tutorial for this ?
This error is close to one I already encountered, it was due to breaking changes from Keycloak 17 which uses Quarkus under the hood.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Which kind of info do you need? No special configuration. I have unzipped the zip file downloaded from keycloak website the ran the kc.bat file and it looks like the space in the folder name is an issue. When you have a space in the folder name it ios generating this error

Comment: Oh i see, if you think it's the space causing the problem, you could try to escape it. See this SuperUser response (for Windows) https://superuser.com/a/279121.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the ")" character in the "c:\program files (x86)" folder name.

There is an issue created on GitLab for this problem.
[github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/19294](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/19294)